# SELECT DISTINCT on 2 or More JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to execute this query with 2 joins in HiveQL but I have this error

```
hive> SELECT distinct ft.status_id
    > FROM fact_tweet ft
    > JOIN place_dimension dp ON (ft.hotspot_id = dp.hotspot_id AND dp.type='park')
    > JOIN dimension_status ds ON (ft.status_id = ds.id AND array_contains(ds.hashtags,'bebop'));
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely Hive server/metastore error. Other queries running ok? Please, check logs for errors and paste them her

Comment: http://dpaste.com/1579654/

I solved with "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" but I didn't  understand the reason.